# Unable to Activate Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am receiving the error..

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors because
>   they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors
>   reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

I referenced other answers and the solution consistently had been to add the subview in viewDidLoad prior to activating constraints programmatically.

I am still receiving however the same crash and do not understand what is causing it. Any guidance would be appreciated. Below is relevant code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var refreshActivityIndicatorView: UIView!

let activityIndicator = AnimationView(name: "name")
let refreshActivityIndicator = AnimationView(name: "name")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    activityIndicatorView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    refreshActivityIndicatorView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    refreshActivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor),
        activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor),
        activityIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: activityIndicatorView.frame.width),
        activityIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: activityIndicatorView.frame.height),
        refreshActivityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: refreshActivityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor),
        refreshActivityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: refreshActivityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor),

    refreshActivityIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: refreshActivityIndicatorView.frame.width),

    refreshActivityIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: refreshActivityIndicatorView.frame.height)
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
refreshActivityIndicatorView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

with

```
refreshActivityIndicatorView.addSubview(refreshActivityIndicator)
```

as those why the crash

```
refreshActivityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: refreshActivityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor),
refreshActivityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: refreshActivityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor), 
refreshActivityIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: refreshActivityIndicatorView.frame.width), 
refreshActivityIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: refreshActivityIndicatorView.frame.height)
```

You set constraints between `refreshActivityIndicatorView` and `refreshActivityIndicator` while `refreshActivityIndicator` isn't added as a subview